# java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am trying to send data from an PageAdapter to a fragment for two days with no success at all.
I am using Bundle, and send like this:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha__completa);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        nome="Chimpanze";

        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Nome_animal",nome);
            Imagem_Animal imagem = new Imagem_Animal();
            imagem.setArguments(bundle);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG,"Erro de bundle: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

And my fragment is like this:

```
public class Imagem_Animal extends Fragment {
    ImageView imagem_p;
    static final String TAG ="Fragmento";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View Layout_imagem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imagem__animal, container, false);
        imagem_p = (ImageView) Layout_imagem.findViewById(R.id.imagem);
        try {
            String nomeAnimal = getArguments().getString("Nome_animal");
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "getStirng :"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return Layout_imagem;
    }
}
```

> Log: getString: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Anybody can help me please?

Thank you very much

Comment: I have trying to send data from an PageAdapter to a fragment? Why don't you just access the data using the MainActivity's context?

Comment: Post and accept your answer.  That will be more helpful for future developer's.

Answer (score 1):

If the Fragment is in your `MainAtivity` actually the `pagerAdapter` is in. Then you can access the field inside `Imagem_Animal` `Fragment` like

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).nome
```

Instead of passing it in a bundle.

Comment: I have tried this way, and keeps returning me the same error :/

Comment: Then check why `nome` field is empty if you are accessing it like above. May be your `Fragment` getting loaded before the variable get initialized. Set your `PagerAdapter` after variables get initialized.

Comment: The error was about a Toast with an incorrect context, not about the getting data! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

create the function in your fragment like below.

```
 public void someFunctionName(String data){

 }
```

in Pager adapter  do the stuff like below.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Imagem_Animal ani= new Imagem_Animal();
    ani.someFunctionName("yourdata");
    return ani;
}
```

That's all

Comment: Thank you very much, but i did with the other sollution :)